# Laravel + ocpp 1.6

Tags: php, laravel, ocpp

My work place want to do our own ocpp server however I am the only web developer here and my most familiar language is php(laravel/native) and I never do this kind of things. Is there anyone can explain/give me source to learn how do i integration between these 2 (charger and laravel app). I tried websocket and ocpp1.6 docs mention boot notification is send when charger boot up but nothing happen so I kind of stuck here. :(

As long as can receive/send request between charger and laravel like boot notification is sufficient for me.